# How to upload video in android using volley

Tags: java, android

I am trying to upload a video on the server, I didn't anything on this, please suggest

I can upload the text, that's working,

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://54.146.132.94/webservices/target_response",
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.i("error", response);

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("error", error.toString());

                    }
                }) {

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        // Posting parameters to login url
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("I_trails", String.valueOf(itr));
                        params.put("E_trails", String.valueOf(et));
                        params.put("D_trails", String.valueOf(dt));
                        params.put("N_trails", String.valueOf(nt));
                        params.put("user_id", String.valueOf(get_id));
                        params.put("target_id", String.valueOf(get_target_id));
                        params.put("session_date", date);
                        params.put("data_mode", data_mode);
                        params.put("mode", mode);
                        params.put("link", link);
                       // params.put("video", selectedPath);
                        params.put("time", time_upload_real);
                        params.put("location_id", LocID);
                        params.put("No_of_trails", String.valueOf(notr));
                        /*params.put("comment", my_comment);*/
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

here the code to upload video, please let me know how to upload this video with the data, that I am uploading.

```
if (null != selectedPath && !selectedPath.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "selected path: "+selectedPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                        uploadFile(selectedPath);
                    }
                }).start();
```

then,

```
public int uploadFile(final String selectedPath){
        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";


        int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File selectedFile = new File(selectedPath);

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL("http://54.146.132.94/webservices/target_response");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("video",selectedPath);


            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video\";filename=\""
                    + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();


            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      //  dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, please let me know how to upload video with that data to the database, I have video path and other value in a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("video/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
```

and after selecting video

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        Uri aa = data.getData();
        mVideoURI = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(aa));
    }
}
```

dont forget to use `private Uri mVideoURI;`
 at top

inside your post volley method use :

```
@Override
                protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                    Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                    /// photo field in link
                    if (mVideoURI != null) {
                        params.put("video", new DataPart("file_avatar.mp4", UploadHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getActivity(), mVideoURI)));
                    }
                    return params;
                }
```

**UPDATE**

1- CREATE BroadcastHelper CLASS :

```
public class BroadcastHelper {
     public static final String BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME = "INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED";
    public static final String ACTION_NAME = "hassan.scott";
    private static final String UPDATE_LOCATION_METHOD = "update";


    public static void sendInform(Context context, String method) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(ACTION_NAME);
        intent.putExtra(BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME, method);
        try {
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void sendInform(Context context, String method, Intent intent) {
        intent.setAction(ACTION_NAME);
        intent.putExtra(BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME, method);
        try {
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

2- Send intent from your adapter

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent url = new Intent("url");
            url ("url_adapter",item.get(position).getURL());
            BroadcastHelper.sendInform(context,"url",url);
        }
    });
```

3- in your fragment this use :

```
Receiver receiver;
boolean isReciverRegistered = false;


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (receiver == null) {
        receiver = new Receiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BroadcastHelper.ACTION_NAME);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        isReciverRegistered = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (isReciverRegistered) {
        if (receiver != null)
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}


private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.v("r", "receive " + arg1.getStringExtra(BroadcastHelper.BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME));
        String methodName = arg1.getStringExtra(BroadcastHelper.BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME);
        if (methodName != null && methodName.length() > 0) {
            Log.v("receive", methodName);
            switch (methodName) {

                case "url":

                    /* call post method here */

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UploadHelper Class :**

```
    public class UploadHelper {

/**
 * Turn drawable resource into byte array.
 *
 * @param context parent context
 * @param id      drawable resource id
 * @return byte array
 */
public static byte[] getFileDataFromDrawable(Context context, int id) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, id);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}

/**
 * Turn drawable into byte array.
 *
 * @return byte array
 */
public static  byte[] getFileDataFromDrawable(Context context, Uri uri) {
    // Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        InputStream iStream =   context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        int bufferSize = 2048;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
        int len = 0;
        if (iStream != null) {
            while ((len = iStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for your time,  .......  params.put("video", new DataPart("file_avatar.mp4", UploadHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getActivity(), mVideoURI)));,______ DataPart,UploadHelper, getActivity is showing error, it shows cannot resolve symbol and when i ALT+ENTER on it, its not showing the option of import. please suggest...

Comment: i am doing coding in adapter  class.

Comment: First of all, you should use broadcast and do your logic in your activity/fragment instead of your adapter

Comment: Tomorrow I can send you broadcast receiver method and class, same with upload-helper

Comment: Thanks for this help

Answer (score 1):

Volley wasn't really meant for video uploading. It is better suited to large in number - small in size uploads/downloads. I would recommend using a different method to upload your video.

> Volley is not suitable for large download or streaming operations,
>   since Volley holds all responses in memory during parsing. For large
>   download operations, consider using an alternative like
>   DownloadManager.*

- Taken from https://developer.android.com/training/volley/

Comment: the doc you quote is about downloading not uploading

Comment: If downloading a video with volley is bad, then uploading it is even more so.

Comment: and why is that?